# Firebird namespace not recognized

Tags: c#, firebird

I started new visual studio project and connected to firebird server, and now i want to connect to database i need firebird.data.sql, but visual studio is not recognizing it for some reason.

I am already working on one project where it is normaly working. Anyone know what to do

Comment: Have you referenced the assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Firebird Client](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/) NuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/) into your project, where you need database connectivity, and put `using` directive for `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` namespace on top of your source code file.